# leak below shower

Tags: shower, leak, sealant

I have discovered a small leak below my shower base. When I slide some paper towels below the shower, and have the water run for 5 minutes, I see around 5 drops of water, probably coming from a hole in the evacuation pipe.

Two questions :

1. How necessary is it to fix this? I have tiles below the shower
2. If I need to fix this, is there a way to put some product inside the evacuation hole that would end up fixing the hole in the pipe?
3. If not, and I need to remove the shower base to plug the hole, what is the right method to break the cement-joint to lift the shower base?

[image: leak 1]

[image: leak 2]

Comment: Why do you suspect a hole in the drain pipe?  Can you see it?  Did something happen that might have caused a hole?

Comment: How were the several sheets in the 2nd pic placed? The 1st pic seems to only show 1 sheet. Are you certain that this isn't splash from the shower itself? Is there any sign of water leaking/damage when looking from below (presuming some accessibility to to a basement, crawlspace, floor below)?

Comment: Yes, some builders just removed it and reinstalled it. They were fairly imcompetent. I ended up unscrewing the drain hole, and confirmed there was water underneath. However I am not sure it is from the drain pipe itself or maybe the joint between the drain hole and the shower base.